# Rails + foreign app

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have rails website that shows information from database. And I have ruby script that should add data in this database. Can I somehow connect this script to my rails app to use its models?

Comment: Can you please give more information? Where is this Ruby script running? What kind of stuff does it do?

Comment: Is this data basically seeding? Or is it a script that is run arbitrarily through normal application use?

Comment: I want to use crontab to run this script. It integrates information another sites.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either load the Rails environment by doing a require

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/config/environment'
```

or use a Rake task (http://railscasts.com/episodes/66-custom-rake-tasks).

Answer (score 1):

You could write a rake task and load in your data to the DB.  Yes, your rake task can reference models and you have access to all the associated AR methods etc.  It goes without saying that you can also run the rake task on development, production etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can add this scripts under lib tasks, tell your rails application to include lib files. Inside those files, you can access rails models to insert data in database.

After that you may run those scripts by calling from rake tasks. Create some rakes under lib/tasks.

Those rake tasks can again be called via cron jobs to work repeatedly for you.